# Vim and NERDTree and Tmux split view causing rendering errors

Tags: vim, tmux, nerdtree, conemu

[See attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BYPv.png)

I was using my setup with Vim and NERDTree and Tmux, where I would open directories or files in a vertical split. Problem is, any file/directory on the right-most panel would wrap on the left side of the page, causing this very weird diagonal rendering bug that I can't get rid of (see attached image). Is this a bug? or can this be resolved using the `.tmux.conf`? (ignore the white boxes, i just censored confidential stuff).

(EDIT): I think this might have something to do with my editor. I'm using [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/), and this problem doesn't seem to get reproduced on other terminal emulators.

Comment: ConEmu version? Shell? Startup task?

Comment: its "Mintty 1.1.3" (not sure why the ConEmu about says Mintty), Shell: Zsh, Startup task: what's that?

Comment: Than you can't say "this problem doesn't seem to get reproduced on other terminal"! You are using mintty, but not a ConEmu! RTFM: [ChildGui](https://conemu.github.io/en/ChildGui.html)

Comment: I have made a huge mistake. Forgive me, I was looking at the wrong thing. It was a long day. "ConEmu 161022 [64]". On ConEmu, there are 2 shells, "git bash" and the new "bash on ubuntu on windows". It works fine on ubuntu one, but bugs out on git bash. weirdly enough, when I open the git bash application (instead or running it on ConEmu) it works fine! So I think this bug happens only on git bash while on ConEmu only.

Comment: There are no proofs that problem is in ConEmu. The terminal just shows what console applications ask. [Third-party application problems](https://conemu.github.io/en/ThirdPartyProblems.html)